# Expected ';' and instead saw ','. - JSLint multivar setting

Tags: javascript, jslint

As of about 14 January 2016, JSLint has started complaining about `var` or `let` declarations that have more than one variable per declaration, and has created a new directive, `multivar` that ignores this new "problem".

This is a pretty significant change, as earlier versions would complain if you *did* have two `var`s in the same code block.

That is, as of today (18 Jan 2016), this code now breaks in [JSLint](http://jslint.com):

```
/*jslint white:true, browser:true, devel:true */
function a(b) {
    "use strict";
    var c, d; // <<< Now bad!!
    d = "test";
    c = d + b;
    console.log(c);
}
```

The error reported is, `Expected ';' and instead saw ','.` for the line `var c,d;`

The "correct" fix is apparently this:

```
/*jslint white:true, browser:true, devel:true */
function a(b) {
    "use strict";
    var c;
    var d;  // <<< this *used* to be forbidden.
    d = "test";
    c = d + b;
    console.log(c);
}
```

Note that this newly correct code would have produced the error, `Error: combine_var`, in [earlier versions of JSLint](http://rufwork.com/jslint).

The only descriptions for the change from Crockford that I can find seem to be [this post on Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736/s/multivar):

> JSLint now has a `multivar` option that tolerates multiple names being declared in a single var, let, or const statement.

... and a quick mention on the [website instructions](http://jslint.com/help.html)...

> Tolerate multiple variables declarations per statement
>   `multivar`
>   `true` if a `var`, `let`, or `const` statement can declare two or more variables in a single statement.

The `multivar` change on JSLint.com doesn't seem to be in the GitHub repo yet. See the two checkins ([1](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/e614782920c19f679623ef2a8132db1584cccf68), [2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/8a49e351072b522a4a7d7328316566e6ede6f8da)) entitled "var" for 14 Jan. Those two make the code in JSLint follow the new requirement, but don't (afaict) add the `multivar` directive described and in use on JSLint.com.

Can anybody tell me why multiple `var` lines are encouraged/required now, other than the usual, "You should ignore JSLint," answers? That is, **why was a single var required before** (I'd guess to encourage an understanding of hoisting), **and why is that reasoning suddenly moot?**

Comment: If you're going to vote down and/or vote to close, a comment why would be awfully helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, but that's a very radical change, I definitely didn't expect that (especially since it's disabled by default).

Comment: Hey @JoshCrozier! Yep, surprised the heck out of me too. It's not just a change, like when JSLint recommended we stop using `for` loops recently, it's a flat 180 from what was required previously.

Comment: Looks like mr. Crockford has rewritten his [Code conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) page too.

Comment: @Teemu Great catch. He does say there, "*It is preferred that each variable declarative statement [be on its own line?] and [include a?] comment*". Unf, even that page doesn't follow this new rule throughout... cf. Function Declarations -- there's no `"use strict"'` and there's a `var array, ncn = node.className;`! I get a `Expected ';' and instead saw ','.` when I lint it. At least that shows this is pretty new, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the AirBNB style guide.

> It's easier to add new variable declarations this way, and you never have to worry about swapping out a ; for a , or introducing punctuation-only diffs. You can also step through each declaration with the debugger, instead of jumping through all of them at once.

More on this at: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables

Comment: Sure, I mean, that makes *sense*, but I'm not sure that's *why*. That is, that's why I have `WHERE 1=1` and then each `AND` clause on its own line when I write SQL, but the strange thing in this case is that JSLint did a complete 180 over what it used to not just encourage, but *require*. A complete answer would explain why the convention completely changed (**Why was a single `var` required before (I'd guess to encourage an understanding of hoisting), and why is that reasoning suddenly moot?**), so +1, but I'll hold out accepting for now.

Comment: Doesn't look like we're going to get a better answer quickly. Going to provisionally accept this one, but if I get a better one later, watch out. :^P

Comment: Having thought about this a bit more, my guess would be that it was an easy way to ensure all vars where at the top of the function. And that the change is to do with the fact that now we have `const` and `let` this no longer makes much sense.