# Multiple variable declaration in one line - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am trying to learn Javascript. I came across the following code.

```
// Random function.
function order_summary(order_object) {
  var x, y;
  // More code here.
}
```

When I run this code in Jslint, it's giving me the following error.

```
Expected ';' and instead saw ','.
var x, y;
```

I don't see any problems with this code. Can anyone explain what this error means?

Comment: It's not a syntax error, it's a suggested style thing that *some* people think it is better to declare every variable separately with separate `var` statements.

Comment: Your editor is probably treating lint issues as errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected ';' and instead saw ','. - JSLint multivar setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862541/expected-and-instead-saw-jslint-multivar-setting)

Comment: Jslint has very strong opinions about how javascript code should be written (it's actually Crockford's opinion but Jslint is the one shouting at you). It's not a syntax checker. It's a "things Crockford does not like" checker. Which to be fair, does avoid a lot of potential bugs. Jslint will hurt your feelings - the website warned you already

Comment: You can try using JSHint. It has its own advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jslint is a sort of a style enforcement tool and doesn't like having multiple variables declared on one line. To fix it, simply declare each variable on each line. e.g.

```
var x;
var y;
```

The reason why jslint doesn't like this is because javascript has semicolon insertion. So if you accidentally omit a comma like this:

```
var x
y = 10;
```

JS will insert the semicolon at the end of the first line and you would have accidentally created a global variable y.

Comment: I think, an accidental _typed_ (or copy-pasted) semicolon in-between `var` declarations is far more likely than an accidental _omitted_ one.

Comment: That makes sense. So it's more of a warning than an error.

Answer (score 3):

There is one very important difference between the two styles:

```
var l1 = 1,
    l2 = 2;
```

and

```
var l1 = 1;
var l2 = 2;
```

Namely: In the second form the debugger can step through each assignment one-by-one.

In the first form, the entire line is one massive expression and the debugger tries to execute it at once.  When you have assignments that depend upon earlier operations, the line-by-line approach is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem at all to declare multiple variables using single var in any javascript run-time. This is just a warning thrown by JSLint as by default it is recommending 1 var per line.

If you check the option "multiple vars" under "Tolerate.." this warning will be ignored.